# Recursively calculating a function

Tags: recursion

Let $f\colon \mathbb N\times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ defined by

- $f(x,0)=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb N$
- $f(0,y)=2y$ for all $ y \in \mathbb Z$
- $x\gt0$ and $y\lt0$$\implies f(x,y)=2y$
- $x\gt0$ and $y\gt0$$\implies f(x,y)=f(x-1, f(x,y-1))$.

Compute $f(3,2)$.

I've restarted this problem several times and always seem to get an incredibly long series of steps that never seem to end. I start with

$f(3,2)=f(2,f(3,1))=f(2,f(2,f(3,0)))=f(2,f(2,3))=....$

and then it goes on for pages. There must be something I'm missing!

Comment: The answer is almost unfathomably large.

Comment: @S.C.B. Then you know not what is unfathomably large in the realm of large finite numbers.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Hey, it seems large to me. Somewhat.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt As written below, it is $2 \uparrow \uparrow 65537$

Comment: @S.C.B. Which is much smaller than $f(9,9)$, for example.  Largeness can only be relative, and $2\uparrow\uparrow65537$ is relatively small to me.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Well, we could do $f(f(9,9),f(9,9))$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(1,x)=g(x)$.

Note that $$g(x)=f(1,x)=f(0, f(1, x-1))=2f(1,x-1)=2g(x-1)$$

Since $g(0)=1$ we conclude that for all non-negative integers $x$, $g(x)=2^{x}$.

Now let $f(2,x)=h(x)$.

Note that since $$g(x)=f(2,x)=f(1,f(2,x-1))=2^{f(2,x-1)}=2^{g(x-1)}$$

Since $h(0)=2$, we recursively see that $h(x)=2\uparrow \uparrow (x+1)$ and in particular $h(3)=65536$ where $\uparrow$ is Knuth's up-arrow notation.

Since $f(3,2)=f(2,h(3))=h(h(3))$, we have that $f(3,2)=2 \uparrow \uparrow 65537$

Comment: I don't follow why $g(x)=2^x$. Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @Alex Use induction. The base case is true since $g(0)=1$. Assume that $g(k)=2^k $ for $k$.  Since $g(x)=2g(x-1), g(k+1)=2^{k+1}$

Comment: @Alex Do you understand now?

Comment: i dont understand how you came up with $2^x$

Comment: or why to define $f(1,x)=g(x)$ for that matter

Comment: @Alex What part don't you understand in the inductive proof above? And I defined $f(1,x)=g(x)$ for simpler notation.

Comment: yes but why $f(1,x)$ and not some other value? I now understand the inductive proof thanks

Comment: @Alex  Because starting with $1$, the smallest natural, makes things much simpler.